# Is there a way to Digress in DialogFlow?

Tags: chatbot, dialogflow-es

I have made a chat bot in IBM Watson that uses Digress, but i tried to find a way to do that in dialogFlow with no sucsess.

Example:

Bot: Welcome
You: I want a large pizza.
Bot: what kind of topping?
You: can you please list the different toppings?
Bot: We have ham,mushroom etc. (Digress to other intent)
Bot: what kind of topping? (Back to original intent)
You: Ham
Bot: Ok.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty simple to implement using Dialogflow's [contexts](https://dialogflow.com/docs/contexts). The intents listed below will model this flow.

The `Pizza` intent applies the context "asked-topping" to the conversation. This means that either of the two following intents, `Select Topping` or `Available Toppings`, can be matched next.

The user could mention a specific topping, which will result in the `Select Topping` intent being matched. Otherwise, they might ask about available toppings, which will result in `Available Toppings` being matched.

If `Available Toppings` is matched, the `asked-topping` context will still be applied after the user's question is answered, so the `Select Topping` intent will still be matchable.

You can play with the [lifespan](https://dialogflow.com/docs/contexts#lifespan) of the intents in order to adjust how many additional questions can be asked before the agent is no longer in the `asked-topping` state. By setting `asked-topping` to a lifespan of 0 after the `Select Topping` intent is matched, we prevent the agent from selecting any more toppings after the pizza has been ordered.

```
Intent: Pizza
Example training phrase: "I want a large pizza"
Response: "what kind of topping?"
Input contexts: <none>
Output contexts: asked-topping (lifespan 2)

Intent: Select Topping
Example training phrase: "Ham"
Response: "Ok"
Input contexts: asked-topping
Output contexts: asked-topping (lifespan 0)

Intent: Available Toppings
Example training phrase: "can you please list the different toppings?"
Response: "We have ham, mushroom etc. What kind of topping?"
Input contexts: asked-topping
Output contexts: <none>
```